# .Net Get Most Common Values in Dictionary List

Tags: .net, linq, dictionary, lambda

I was looking all over stackoverflow and this kind of question was never asked so I decided to ask it and I figured out the solution so I might as well post it in the answers section.

[image]

Lets say you got as the Key value a unique function address and the Value value is just a value that could be common but also could be random.. and you want to extract all the Key address values with the value that is most common and also want to get the value alone thats the most common for further processing.

Here is how I solved it.

```
        var MostCommonDictionaryValuesFirst = PersonalCraft_SubOffset1_FunctionAddress.GroupBy(_ => _.Value).OrderByDescending(_ => _.Count()).SelectMany(_ => _);
```

Comment: That's Int array.. i need a multi-element array dictionary

Comment: So what? Its exactly the same operations you do - what kind of value your dict has is not importatnt as long as you can group it - and the things to do are the same regardless if int or class instance or whatnot. he solution there is exactly the same as your posted one: groupby, OrderBy, count ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Get most common value first
var GetMostCommonValue = PersonalCraft_SubOffset1_FunctionAddress.GroupBy(_ => _.Value).OrderByDescending(_ => _.Count()).SelectMany(_ => _).First().Value;

//Get a list of diction values that occur most common first.
var MostCommonDictionaryValuesFirst = PersonalCraft_SubOffset1_FunctionAddress.GroupBy(_ => _.Value).OrderByDescending(_ => _.Count()).SelectMany(_ => _);

//This gives you a nice list of all most common addresses.
var GetMostCommonAddresses = PersonalCraft_SubOffset1_FunctionAddress.Where(t => t.Value == GetMostCommonValue).ToList();
//This has a sorted list of most common first.. but still needs to remove non-most common from list.. so needs work
var GetMostCommonFirst = PersonalCraft_SubOffset1_FunctionAddress.GroupBy(_ => _.Value).OrderByDescending(_ => _.Count()).SelectMany(_ => _);
```

still don't know how to remove values that are not most common from dictionary list